# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

Got When I Run my JSP project on Netbeans 7.3
 How to solve this ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because there is a number to long in the code, maybe go back and check if you added a number to long and you just need to change it, check all of the integers!